# Wildcards in Monit paths?

Tags: monit

Is it possible to use wildcards in Monit file check ?

For example monitoring all the bar* files in directory /tmp/foo ?

```
CHECK FILE bar WITH PATH /tmp/foo/bar*
    IF ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Each check must have an unique name. You should refine your goal here and study why you want this behavior.

Comment: I was afraid of that. My intention was to make a generic Monit script which would work for any system generating those files. Which would all be named in a system specific way. Hence the wild card.

Comment: You could some clever way to monitor the directory (add/remove file) then trigger the execution of a custom script to add/remove a generated file to add/remove an monit check for this file and perform "monit reload" to take into account the configuration change with something like -> check directory bar path /tmp/foo/
   if changed timestamp then exec "/pat/to/custom/script.sh"